# adding value to a cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having multiple sheets in an excel file

`sheet1`  contains some data from `A1 to A100`

`sheet2`  in this sheet `row1` contains the data with numeric value

in `sheet2` if `A1` contains the 0 `A3` should be the value of `A1` of `sheet1`

in `sheet2` if `A1` contains the 30 `A3` should be the value of `A1+30` that is `A31` of `sheet1`

Any idea how to get the described behavior?

Comment: may i know why i got -1 for this i searched alot for this but nothing i got if any one can help please help on this

Comment: while the downvote wasn't mine ... (1) this is not programming, it belongs at Super User. (2) your question didn't show any evidence that you had tried anything yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something involving `INDIRECT`. Not sure what your data looks like, but from what it sounds like, you would want to put a formula like this in `A3` in `Sheet2`:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & A1 + 1)
```

That will get the value in `A1`, add 1 (0->1, 30->31) and then concatenate it with the `Sheet1!A` string, giving you a reference to a cell on the first sheet. Using `INDIRECT` then returns the value at that cell.

Comment: yes it works but i failed to give the correct sheet name here

Comment: @KMKMAHESH What won't work? I didn't downvote, but I imagine that it is the relative lack of information/previously code you've tried that got it. Happy to help, but will need a little more information as to the constraints.